# How to construct csrfmiddlewaretoken from a given csrftoken using javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, postman

I'm working how to login to a django site with postman. 
Using Charles I can see that a csrfmiddlewaretoken token is created somehow.

Given

```
csrftoken=JDmmXqnLK35WCLha1PVOhFWITaKZs9eeAWBfuqXUxZEt3yDHmNoOyzMyJUQF5aQd
```

the csrfmiddlewaretoken sent was

```
v3I6Io9H8OoZcp4ATyszhAepdQAEp617mmXZfoJQVKXwDcq7ewVzyu4f3AGk27D6
```

Can 
    v3I6Io9H8OoZcp4ATyszhAepdQAEp617mmXZfoJQVKXwDcq7ewVzyu4f3AGk27D6 
be constructed from
    JDmmXqnLK35WCLha1PVOhFWITaKZs9eeAWBfuqXUxZEt3yDHmNoOyzMyJUQF5aQd 
using javascript?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with constructing the csrf token in Javascript?

Comment: The only thing that is different from what works and what fails from what I can see is providing csrfmiddlewaretoken. Using a browser and charles csrfmiddlewaretoken is present in the http calls. I'm looking to create csrfmiddlewaretoken to send in with a postman post request and hopefully log into the system.

Comment: In asking the question I had the idea that the site might be generating it ... and it was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this issue was understanding where csrfmiddlewaretoken came from.
I thought it was constructed somehow from csrftoken.
I realised it must of been a hidden variable supplied by the server.

So the problem then became how to extract the csrfmiddlewaretoken value from the initial get call to login. Note Postman now uses cheerio having dropped jQuery.

Using postman jetpack in the get call this is the test that I used to extract the hidden input value.

```
tests["responseCode.code === 200"] = responseCode.code === 200 ;
var csrftoken = postman.getResponseCookie("csrftoken").value ;
tests['csrftoken: ' + csrftoken ] = csrftoken.length > 0 ;
var html ;
html = cheerio(responseBody) ;
inputs = html.find('input') ;
csrfmiddlewaretoken = '' ;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfmiddlewaretoken) ;
for( var index = 0 ; index < inputs.length ; index++) {
    var input = inputs[index] ;
    if ( input.attribs.name === 'csrfmiddlewaretoken') {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken = input.attribs.value ;
        postman.setEnvironmentVariable("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfmiddlewaretoken) ;
    }
}
tests['csrfmiddlewaretoken: ' + csrfmiddlewaretoken ] = csrfmiddlewaretoken.length > 0 ;
```

then in the post call to actually login.

I had to add a Referer header according to the sites security policy.

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer:{{referer}}
```

The form values

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:{{csrfmiddlewaretoken}}
username:{{username}}
password:{{password}}
next:{{next}}
```

and then on sending the post call the postman script successfully logged in

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the CSRF token just to log in through postman, you can do two things:

1. Either use the developer tools and get the csrf middleware token by inspecting your form and looking for hidden csrfmiddleware input field.
   (This will work in case of server side rendering)
2. Get the csrf token from the cookie. Here is a JQuery utility that the Django docs have mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/)

   ```
   function getCookie(name) {
       var cookieValue = null;
       if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
           var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
           for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
               var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
               // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
               if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                   cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       return cookieValue;
   }
   var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
   ```

Once you get the CSRF token, just add a header to your request in POSTMAN with key `X-CSRFToken` and the value as the csrf token.

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: No. I've worked out a solution. I'll post it once I have it working.